# How to put a gradient in the left side corner?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the Divi Theme of Elegant Themes I am trying to put a gradient behind the text in my full width slider module. I am having a problem with the gradient area in the sense that I am not capable of getting the gradient to start at the left side of the picture.

When I am applying the gradient in my code the position of my text is also changing. Could somebody help me to solve this problem?
This is the code that I am using:

```
<div style="padding: 0px;">
    <strong>&nbsp;</strong>

    &nbsp;

    &nbsp;

    &nbsp;

    &nbsp;

    &nbsp;

    <span style="color: #ffffff;">
        <strong>
            <span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 54px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 75px;">
                De Banden Specialisten
            </span>
        </strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything that would generate a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

i think that a proper gradient background would look like this:

```css
        .grad {

          background: rgb(240, 183, 161);

          background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 50%, rgba(117, 34, 1, 1) 51%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);

          background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(117, 34, 1, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1)));

          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 50%, rgba(117, 34, 1, 1) 51%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);

          background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 50%, rgba(117, 34, 1, 1) 51%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);

          background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 50%, rgba(117, 34, 1, 1) 51%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);

          background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 50%, rgba(117, 34, 1, 1) 51%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);

          filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f0b7a1', endColorstr='#bf6e4e', GradientType=1);

        }
```

```html
<div style="padding: 0px;">

  <strong>&nbsp;</strong>
  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

  <span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong><span class="grad" style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'; 
        font-size: 54px;  padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; 
        padding-bottom: 75px;">De Banden Specialisten</span>
  </strong>
  </span>

</div>
```

also, you could easily create your own css custom gradient background with this cool site:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
it has a very easy editor, and generates css output of the wanted gradient